# Rails delayed_job is using a different time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

So I'm trying to figure out why my delayed jobs aren't running, and I think I might have an idea.

I'm not sure if it's the time difference or what's going on just yet, but here's the first issue that I'm noticing.

```
irb(main):002:0> Delayed::Job.first
  Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `delayed_jobs`.* FROM `delayed_jobs` ORDER BY `delayed_jobs`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 8, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject...", last_error: nil, run_at: "2018-02-25 05:50:00", locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil, locked_by: nil, queue: nil, created_at: "2018-02-25 05:40:47", updated_at: "2018-02-25 05:40:47">
```

In the above command output, it shows that the job will run on 02/25/18 at 5:50 AM. However, in the Rails app I scheduled this job to run on 02/24/18 at 11:50 PM CST.

If I run `Time.now` from the Rails console, this is the output that I get:

```
irb(main):003:0> Time.now
=> 2018-02-24 23:46:15 -0600
```

The funny thing is that when I run the `Delayed::Job.all` command, I can see that the `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes are in the wrong time zone or something as well. So is Delayed::Job only going to run based on what's configured with `Time.now`?

In my `config/application.rb` file I do have the time zone configured as Central, as shown below:

```
[nutella:~/rails_apps/instaweb]$ cat config/application.rb| grep -i time                                                                                       11:49PM/02.24
    config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
```

A little confused as to why the delayed job isn't running and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line too to application.rb :

`config.active_record.default_timezone = :local`

Comment: Tried adding that and then restarting the rails server. It looks like the `Delayed::Job.all` command still shows an output of scheduled tasks for 6 hours from now. Will it actually run 6 hours from now? Or will it run based on UTC (meaning if I schedule it to run in 5 minutes, it'll run in 5 minutes)? I almost feel like it's scheduling for UTC, but will run when it hits that time based on local time.

Comment: Alright. Can you tell me what does it show when you run ````Delayed::Job.first.run_at.zone```` in the rails console?

Comment: Great. So isn't that the desired result? Or there's still any discrepancy when a delayed job is created?

Comment: still a weird discrepancy. the created and updated at times are still in a different time zone

Comment: Alright. Try different combinations of those two config lines by commenting them one at a time.

Comment: Still no luck, unfortunately. Everything seems to be in CST except for the run_at, updated_at, and created_at time. That doesn't make any sense to me because the above command just showed CST. Isn't that conflicting?

Answer (score 0):

So I went through the troubleshooting guide and it looks like I didn't have the delayed_job process actually started. Now that I was able to get this sorted out, all is well. I appreciate everyone's help!